# Finding the number of elements in a set when given the limits and the mean.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory

Suppose that **n** is a positive integer and that the set **S** contains **n** distinct **positive integers**. If the mean of the elements of **S** is equal to **2/5 of the largest element** of S and is also equal to **7/4 of the smallest element** of **S**, what would be the minimum possible value of **n**?

I took *x* to represent the smallest integer of the set and *y* to represent the largest integer. Since the mean gotten both ways are equal:

```
   2/5y=7/4x
      y=35/8x
```

the range of values will be:

```
    x<S>35/8x {Inclusive}
```

Since the elements of the set are all positive integers, I assumed that the smallest value of *x* would be *8* so the elements would range from *8* to *35* {inclusive}
with this assumption the mean I would be hoping to find would be 14 but getting values of the individual elements is annoying because the number of elements isn't set in stone even if the mean is and whenever I guess a value for *n* and try deducing the individual values from that, they are either outside the range completely or simply aren't integers. I would appreciate the working to follow to get the value of n.

Comment: Seems like a good start.  Taking $(8,35)$ as endpoints of your set, you would need the average to be $14$.  I'd use that to construct a good set.  Try $(8,9,35)$ and so on.  Once you find a good set (easily done), you'll need to argue that there is no smaller one of course.

Comment: Note:  the set you find in the way I suggested is *not* minimal, but the principle works.

Comment: @lulu I keep trying to but for some reason the other values are always outside the range. If assume n=4 the sum of the other 2 values should be 13 but it is literally impossible to have both values above 8 and distinct.

Comment: So, follow the pattern I suggested.  Try $(8,9,35)$.  If that fails, try $(8,9,10,35)$ and so on.  That method at least gives you a small good example.  It's not minimal, but you can do the same thing with $(16,70)$.  I think the example you get that way is minimal, but some work would be needed to prove that.

Comment: To stress:  the goal of my method is to produce some small examples.  At least that bounds $n$ and then you just have to eliminate smaller values.